# Localization using i18n in angular 7 is not working after deployment to Azure

Tags: .net-core, internationalization, angular7, angular-i18n, angular7-router

I'm following this [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-localization-in-angular-using-i18n-tools-a88898b1a0d0/) to implement localization in Angular using i18n.

When i navigate to "url/en" or "url/fr", instead of pointing to respective directory folders it is trying to search for a route and giving the below error message.

```
core.js:15723 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'fr'
```

I have created this Angular 7 project using VS2019.
For the backend i'm using asp.net core 2.2 web api.

Running following commands shows the page with the correct translations locally.

> ng serve --configuration=fr

My angular.json file as shown below.
[image]

My Package.json file as shown below
[image]

I have configured route in this way in app.modules.ts

> ```
> RouterModule.forRoot([
>   {
>     path:'',      
>     component:HomeComponent,
>     canActivate:[AuthGuard]
>   },
> ```

I modified the .csproj file in this way.

```
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
<!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build-locale" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build-locale:ssr" Condition=" '$(BuildServerSideRenderer)' == 'true' " />
```

Here are my directory structure
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should overide the url on Web server level. For example add web.config:

```
    <rule name="FR Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(fr/)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/fr/" />
    </rule>
```